# Linux, dev-mapper: How to mount a folder with different options than parent folder

Tags: linux, mount, centos7, fstab, device-mapper

I'm using CentOS 7.1 with device-mapper, and /home mounted as

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

I'd like to include in fstab an entry for mounting /home/xyz with different options than those for /home (e.g. noatime)

I've tried on a PC that doesn't have dev-mapper:

```
mkdir /xyz
mount --bind /home/xyz/ /xyz -o noatime
```

Would the next line in fstab work? Is there an easier (more simple) way? Do I need to run some other command for Device Mapper?

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home-xyz /home/xyz xfs noatime
```

Comment: Device-mapper has nothing to do with it. What is the business problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Michael, I've /home mounted as described in the first line (one of it's options is relatime), I'd like to have /home/xyz mounted with option noatime

Comment: That's not the business problem you're trying to solve.